# Vagrant treating WSL as Linux on one machine (treats WSL as Windows elsewhere)

Tags: ruby, vagrant, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vagrant-windows, trellis

We are using Trellis and Vagrant to provision developer WordPress instances on windows machine (within the Windows Subsystem for Linux.) On one machine we are having a lot of issues, and have managed to figure out that the `Vagrant::Util::Platform.platform` variable is set to `mingw32` on the machines that work well, but it is set to `linux-gnu` on the problematic machine.

Tracing back a bit further to https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/blob/master/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb it appears that Vagrant uses `RbConfig::CONFIG["host_os"]` to determine the platform.

Not sure where to proceed from there - what would cause Ruby to report Linux in the WSL of one machine, but Windows on the WSL of another machine?

Comment: are you using the same shell (and version) on all machines ?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri That definitely put us in the right direction - we identified that the developer had set up the machine differently, so that it included tools like ruby that were running as Linux versions, but on our machines it is the Windows flavours that are running. I will get an answer up once we've fully sorted out the issue.